# Checking if an error is readable native map

Tags: react-native, toast, android-toast

My clients have the app hang/crash and it cannot be replicated, so I'm trying to pretend and log an error:

```
try {
  console.log(z); // put intentional error in code block that may be problematic
  // API call here
} catch (e) {
  try {
    ToastAndroid.show(e, ToastAndroid.SHORT);
  } catch (error) {
    // it is not an API call error that can be displayed!
    Sentry.captureException(e);
  }
}
```

I got this error for trying to show the error of console.log(z); in the toast, although I have put a second try catch block:
[image]

I want to log the error in sentry only if its not an API call error/cant be shown in toast, how do I do this?

Comment: message for `ToastAndroid` should be string, but you pass an error object to it.